# map specialization of a class template to Int template argument

Tags: c++, pointers, function-templates, class-template

I have a template class like:

```
//Node.hh

class voidNode
{
    //class stuff
}

template<class T> : public voidNode
Node
{
    public:
    Node() { };
    ~Node() { };
    // class stuff
}
```

I require to build a function that return a pointer certain specialization for this template class, depending on another template parameter, something like:

```
//fun.hh
//pseudocode

template<int N>
Node<fun(N)> *getElement()
{
    voidNode *ptr{nullptr};
    if(N == 1)
      return dynamic_cast<Node<uint32_t>*>(ptr);
    else if(N == 2)
      return dynamic_cast<Node<int32_t>*>(ptr);
              .
              .
              .
     else if(N == n)
      return dynamic_cast<Node<another_type>*>(ptr);
}
```

So I can call this function like:

```
Node<uint32_t> *a = getElement<0>();
Node<int32_t> *b = getElement<1>();
Node<bool> *c = getElement<whatever_number>();
```

However, I only know how to specifically set the return type like:

```
template<typename T>
Node<T> *getElement()
{
    voidNode *ptr{nullptr};
    return dynamic_cast<Node<T>*>(ptr);
}
```

But having it this way is not what I need.
To let make it clearer, I need some way to map int to certain data type, but most importantlty, I don't know the correct syntax for "template **Node<fun(N)>** *getElement()"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this looks a little like you are trying to reinvent `std::tuple`

Comment: @RyanHaining I'm trying to implement a light-weight double linked list whose nodes store different data types. I'm stuck at the part when each node has to return the according data type.

Comment: What does `fun(n)` mean? Did you try turning all of your `if` expressions into `if constexpr`, and simply declaring the return type as `auto`?

Comment: Have a look at ````std::variant```` before you go further. "Storing different data types" is exactly why it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I would first add a template type for the sake of listing the types that I want to return

```
template <typename ... T> struct TypeList {};
```

and then another template type to pick one of them

```
template <int i, typename ... T> struct GetType {};

template <int i, typename First, typename ... Rest>
struct GetType<i, First, Rest...> {
  typedef typename GetType<i-1, Rest...>::type type;
};

template <typename First, typename ... Rest>
struct GetType<0, First, Rest...> {
  typedef First type;
};

template <int i, typename ... T>
struct GetType<i, TypeList<T...>> {
  typedef typename GetType<i, T...>::type type;
};
```

and then use it like this:

```
struct MyClass {
  typedef TypeList<int, float> Types;

  template<int N>
  Node<typename GetType<N, Types>::type>* getElement()
  {
    voidNode *ptr{nullptr};
    return reinterpret_cast<Node<typename GetType<N, Types>::type>*>(ptr);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand it, however, I can't identify the use of the variadic Arguments. Could you please help me to understand that part, please.

Comment: When you see three dots, `...`, it means something is variadic, e.g. in `typename ... T`. If you google "C++ variadic template" you will find lots of information about how it works.